# Logo Комментарии

Tags: комментарии

Как делать **комментарии** в языке **Лого**?

В интернете читал, что комментарии делаются с помощью `;`, но среда разработки (LogoWriter) выдаёт ошибку.

Может проблема в среде разработки? Или в русскоязычной интерпретации данного языка?

Comment: А можете написать, какая именно ошибка выдаётся LogoWriter?

Comment: @4500zenja, "**не знаю что делать с ;<комментарий>**"